# Software to make math substitution animations

Tags: math, animation

I'd like to make some animations for a presentation showing math function-like substitutions. For example, given

```
f(x) = x + x
```

and

```
f(2)
```

the animation would show starting with both, then `2` being substituted for `x` in `x + x`, and the result of that replacing `f(2)`, with the various items sliding around the screen so you can see the substitution happening visually.

What I *really* need is to show substitution for lambda calculus expressions, like `(\x.x) (\x.x)`, which is very similar, so if there's software tailored for that, even better.

Comment: This depends on the presentation software (e.g. PowerPoint, LaTeX Beamer/PDF) you will be using. Second question: Do you need a real animation or is simply appearing/disappearing of the objects sufficient?

Comment: I'm interested in any solution. I can use whatever it takes. I need a real animation, although I imagine stuff might disappear in the animation after substitution.

Answer (score 1):

[Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) and [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/)?

http://www.akb.me.uk/equations

[image]

Though to be honest, once your expressions have been converted to SVG (like MathJax does here) you could save it (or even screen-grab, trim and save as an image).  Then you'd probably get a much better software recommendation for how do I create an animation from such files.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good start, although more heavy lifting than I was hoping.

Comment: @indil yeah, that turned out more involved than I was hoping too